# Error: Address in use 1883 mosquito Docker

Tags: linux, mqtt, mosquitto

Getting error on starting mosquito docker in ubuntu 16.04.

```
@biswanath:~$ docker logs mosquitto-test
1609346169: mosquitto version 1.6.12 starting
1609346169: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1609346169: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1609346169: Error: Address in use
```

Though I have uninstall all the previous installation of mousquitto. But Ports(1883) are still in use by mosquitto. Need help to free this port 1883.

```
@biswanath:~$ sudo lsof -i TCP:1883
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mosquitto 2185 root    4u  IPv4  27174      0t0  TCP *:1883 (LISTEN)
mosquitto 2185 root    5u  IPv6  27175      0t0  TCP *:1883 (LISTEN)

@biswanath:~$ sudo systemctl stop mosquitto
Failed to stop mosquitto.service: Unit mosquitto.service not loaded.
```

When tried to kill with **kill -9 PID** it recreate again.

```
@biswanath:~$ ps ax | grep mosq
13719 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh /snap/mosquitto/387/launcher.sh
13759 ?        S      0:00 /snap/mosquitto/387/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /snap/mosquitto/387/default_config.conf
14802 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mosq
@biswanath:~$ sudo kill -9 13719
@biswanath:~$ sudo killall -9 mosquitto
@biswanath:~$ ps ax | grep mosq
14931 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh /snap/mosquitto/387/launcher.sh
14972 ?        S      0:00 /snap/mosquitto/387/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /snap/mosquitto/387/default_config.conf
14978 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mosq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have another instance of Mosquitto already running.

Use `ps ax | grep mosq` to see if Mosquitto is still running outside of a container. If you find it, use `sudo kill -9 PID` where you replace PID with its process ID. Or you can try `sudo killall -9 mosquitto`.

If that doesn't solve the problem, check Docker.

Use `docker ps` to list all the Docker containers currently running.

Use `docker stop ID` where you replace the ID for each container that's running.

If you fail to find an instance of Mosquitto, reboot your computer and try again.

Comment: I have tried this already. The thing is happening that it kill but it recreate with different process ID.

Comment: Then you haven't uninstalled it and it's still being managed by systemd. Maybe you installed it multiple times? It looks like you installed it using `snap`, so try `snap remove mosquitto`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are running mosquitto from snap.

You can stop the snap with the following commands:

```
 $ snap stop mosquoitto
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to start Mosquitto twice, the first time is a leftover from earlier versions that need deletion. The words below are from a post in another thread.

There was a root CRON job that runs `launcher.sh` which contained `sudo mosquitto -d`

How did I find it. Well once I found CRON has a @reboot option I looked further and found CRON is by user including root.  So I winged it and tried `sudo crontab -l`  hoping the use of sudo finds root cronjobs instead of pi user jobs and there as a another job.

After that it was a tidy up of all the other things I had tweaked and re-enable the systemd job on reboot. `sudo systemctl enable mosquitto.service`

So now have 2.0.11 working as I like.  I suspect that CRON job was a left over from earlier versions of Mosquitto (I was on 1.5 or 1.6) but the update to 2.0.11 didn't delete it when it created the mosquitto.service job.